# Why laravel don't show bootstrap from controller?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.1

When I try to return a view from a route like this:

```
Route::get('/testid', function () { 
        $id = 1; // for test only
        $title = 'Dashboard';
        $username=Auth::user()->name;
        $job=Auth::user()->job;
        $p = 1; 

        $requestedorder = \App\Order::findOrfail($id);
        return view('ViewOrder',compact('requestedorder','title','username','job','p'));

});
```

in the browser it shows up normally like any bootstrap view

but when this view is returned from a controller

```
public function show($id) 
{
    $title = 'Dashboard';
    $username=Auth::user()->name;
    $job=Auth::user()->job;
    $p = 1; 

    $requestedorder = Order::findOrfail($id);
    return view('ViewOrder',compact('requestedorder','title','username','job','p'));
}
```

the view be like this without any bootstrap or any css or even without images : http://1drv.ms/1m7N8Yk

I noticed that this problem occures in any url with id like this "http://localhost:8000/testid/1"

this is vieworder view

```
@extends('WDashBoard')


@section('content2')

<div>

<h1>Order Details</h1>
<hr>



     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5><B>From :</B></h5>
          </div>                        
          <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                <h5> {{ $requestedorder->customeremail }}</h5>
          </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
               <h5><B>Details :</B></h5>
          </div>                        
          <div class="col-sm-9"> 
               <h5>{{ $requestedorder->details }}</h5>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5><B>Required Work :</B></h5>
           </div>                        
           <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                <h5>{{ $requestedorder->requiredwork }}</h5>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <h5><B>Date :</B></h5>
            </div>                        
            <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                 <h5> {{ $requestedorder->date }}</h5>
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <h5><B>Time :</B></h5>
            </div>                        
            <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                  <h5>{{ $requestedorder->time }}</h5>
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <h5><B>Message :</B></h5>
            </div>                        
            <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                 <h5>{{ $requestedorder->message }}</h5>
            </div>
       </div>

</div>

@stop
```

and this is my DashBoard view

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')

    <section class="slider2">
            <div class="slider-wrap2">          
                <h1>DashBoard</h1>
            </div> 
    </section>
    <section class="container">                       

          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="dash">
                    <br><br>
                    <center><img src="images/default-avatar.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" /></center>
                    <center><h3> {{ $username }} </h3></center> 
                    <center><h4> {{ $job }} </h4></center>
                    <br>

                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li class="nav-header"></li>
                        <li><a href="/profile"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>     
                        My Profile</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="/orders"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>     
                        Requested Orders</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <br><br><br><br>

                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-9">

               @yield('content2')

               </div>
           </div>
<br>
                </section>

@stop
```

and this is master view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>{{ $title }}</title>

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Elegant icon font -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/line-icons.min.css">
    <!-- Animation -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Prettyphoto -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css">
    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
    <!-- Scrolling nav css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scrolling-nav.css">
    <!-- Template styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Responsive styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" >




<!-- Header start -->
  <header id="header" role="banner" >
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"  id="tf-menu">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Logo start -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href="#" class="page-scroll">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo1.png" alt="logo">
                </a> 
              </div>                   
          </div><!--/ Logo end -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse clearfix navMenu" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="/" >Home</a></li>




                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="/about" >About</a></li>

                            <li><font style="opacity:.1">....................</font></li>
@if($p == 0)
                               <li><a href="/login" ><small>SignIn</small></a></li>


                               <li><a href="/register"><small>Register</small></a></li>

@endif
@if($p == 1)

                                <li><a href="/profile" ><small>hi {{ $username }}</small></a></li>

                                <li><a href="/auth/logout"><small>Logout</small></a></li>
@endif
                </ul>



              </div><!--/ Navigation end -->
        </div><!--/ Row end -->
      </div><!--/ Container end -->
    </nav>
  </header><!--/ Header end -->
    <!-- END MAIN NAV -->


      @yield('content')



  <!-- section Footer start  -->
  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="footer-content text-center">
            <a href="#slider-part" class="page-scroll logo-title">
              <img src="images/blackbg.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <ul class="footer-socail list-inline">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="copyright">
                <p> copyright &copy; <span>mycompany</span> - 2015</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- row end  -->
    </div> <!-- container end  -->
  </footer>
  <!-- section Footer end  -->



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- initialize jQuery Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Style Switcher -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/isotope.js"></script>
    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <!-- PrettyPhoto -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <!-- Isotope -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/isotope.js"></script>
    <!-- Wow Animation -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SmoothScroll -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
    <!-- Eeasing -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Counter -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Waypoints -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Scrolling navigation -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Map API Key Source -->
    <!--<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>-->
    <!-- Custom js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapjs.js"></script>



  <script>
    new WOW().init();
  </script>
    <script>

   $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 100,
            time: 2000
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `/ViewOrder` and `/Craftsman/ViewOrder` are the same?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm sorry now it is edited but this is not my problem the view name is the same in my app

Comment: Check the developpers console in your browser please.

Comment: Try to replace `<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`  by `<link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using relative paths in your HTML that are not properly mapping to your assets through your 'folder' structure.

Have you wrapped your asset URLs in the `asset()` helper function in your view?

```
<link href="{{ asset( 'path/to/asset' ) }}" rel="stylesheet">

<img src="{{ asset( 'path/to/image' ) }}">
```

Remember, use of the `/` means you're in a 'subfolder' in traditional URL-to-Unix-style path mapping, so your asset references need to account for that.

Thankfully, Laravel makes this super easy with the [URL helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-action).

Comment: thanks but every thing is correct in my view and it show up normally like this from the routes file : http://1drv.ms/1YAAmmb
but the problem is when it returned from a controller be like this :http://1drv.ms/1m7N8Yk

Comment: It's exactly as I suspected. Please re-read my answer as this provides exactly the solution you require.